# How to insert multiple rows updating-outbound-gateway?

Tags: spring-integration

I am using `<updating-outbound-gateway>` to insert the record using nativeQuery. 
How can I pass List so that multiple records can be inserted in DB?

```html
<int-jpa:updating-outbound-gateway native-query="insert into PARTNER_RESPONSE_DETAILS(PARTNER_ID,BANK_REFERENCE_NUMBER,REQUEST_STRING,RESPONSE_STRING,RESPONSE_DATE) values (:partnerId,:bankReferenceNumber,:requestString,:responseString,:responseDate)"
entity-manager="entityManager">
 <int-jpa:transactional />
 <int-jpa:parameter name="partnerId"    expression="payload['partnerId']" />
 <int-jpa:parameter name="bankReferenceNumber"  expression="payload['bankReferenceNumber']" />
 <int-jpa:parameter name="requestString"    expression="payload['requestString']" />
 <int-jpa:parameter name="responseString"   expression="payload['responseString']" />
 <int-jpa:parameter name="transactionStatus"  expression="payload['transactionStatus']" />
 <int-jpa:parameter name="responseDate"    expression="payload['responseDate']" />
</int-jpa:updating-outbound-gateway>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it isn't possible with JPA Native Query to perform bulk update, the `<int-jpa:updating-outbound-gateway>` doesn't provide that functionality.

It is possible with the regular `EntityManager.persist()` though.

You task you can fix with the `<splitter>` in front of that `<int-jpa:updating-outbound-gateway>`. If you do that in the single thread, there won't be performed DB call until the TX commit after all the records.

Comment: thanks Artem , how can i implement Multi-thread so that it commits after every insert ?

Comment: `ExecutorChannel` after splitter. But that is fully opposite story of what you are asking here...

Comment: i have 2 record in the list for insert , one is insert successfully and second one throws SQL exception , it  should rollback both record , but i can see first record is inserted successfully .but if first record throws exception then nothing is inserted.

Comment: Feel free to raise a new SO question with particular config and proper description.